# oci_err() undefined error with MediaWiki and Oracle backend

Tags: oracle, mediawiki, sles

Installed MediaWiki (git master) with Oracle 11 as the database.  Post installation, the MainPage does not display but shows instead:

```
Warning: oci_parse() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...MediaWiki/includes/db/DatabaseOracle.php on line 1266 
Warning: oci_error() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in ...MediaWiki/includes/db/DatabaseOracle.php on line 1271
```

Now, I assume I can ignore these warnings, so I attempted to run `../maintenance/update.php --quick` and received:

```
MediaWiki 1.24alpha Updater

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function oci_error() in ...MediaWiki/includes/db/DatabaseOracle.php on line 522

Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_error() in ...MediaWiki/includes/db/DatabaseOracle.php on line 522
```

The code at line 522 is:

```php
    function lastError() {
                if ( $this->mConn === false ) {
                        $e = oci_error();
                } else {
                        $e = oci_error( $this->mConn );
                }

                return $e['message'];
        }
```

Why isn't `oci_error()` defined if oci8 is installed?

Comment: It looks like opened a bug with MediaWiki, Bill? https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71068.  Make sure the OCI extension is enabled in your PHP installation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Yes, I did open a bug.  I'm spreading the net far and wide, as I'd like to get this working this weekend.  The extension appears to be installed correctly and there is an entry in php.ini as well.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: Do a sanity check with `phpinfo()`, if you haven't already.  It'll confirm whether or not OCI8 is installed, and if you're picking up the right .ini file.

Comment: Already done.  It confirms OCI8 is installed.  I'm not sure what the wrong ini files would be, but it's picking up /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 0):

[WMAT's answer](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T73068#772061): This was caused by PHP on SLES not calling the correct php.ini.